# How to generate co-occurrence matrix (only) in Mahout

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I couldn't find a way to generate only co-occurrence matrix given a preference input file (userID, itemID and optional rating) in Mahout. Is that possible? All I can find is generating a recommendation output and co-occurrence matrix seems to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Mahout provides a class called ItemSimilarityJob which computes co-occurrence data.